# Typewriter font for Math Mode

Tags: math-mode, math-fonts

Does there exist a package that gives typewriter text both in regular and math mode, with italicization in math mode, typewriter greek letters (e.g. \alpha) and symbols?

I know you could do $\mathtt{equations}$ around everything, but surely there has to be a better way (plus it doesn't work with symbols).

Comment: Maybe one option could be to [mix LMMonoPropLt10-Regular with Concrete math](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENm8r.png)?

Comment: @mickep That's perfect! Thank you! I have somehow never seen it before on any other posts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I copied the file `amsldoc.tex` from

```
/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/doc/latex/amsmath/amsldoc.tex
```

(you can also find it on CTAN) into a file `ttmath.tex` and added after the `\documentclass` line

```
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{Latin Modern Mono}
\setmathfont{Concrete Math}

\AtBeginDocument{\raggedright}
```

Compile with LuaLaTeX. Some examples

[image]

[image]

[image]